# RestSharp - Token authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, restsharp

I'm trying to send a GET request with a token authentication, but i get an unauthorized response.
If i send the same request on Postman, it works.

Here's my code :

```
string url = string.Format("{0}batchs", MyUrl);
RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
RestRequest getRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
getRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
getRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "token " + MyToken);
getRequest.AddParameter("name", MyName, ParameterType.QueryString);

IRestResponse getResponse = client.Execute(getRequest);
```

And here's my postman request :

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10J0p.png)

Any ideas on how to correct this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Adding your postman request/response headers here might help

Comment: Are you definitely using `Authorization: token TOKENVALUE`

Comment: Postman request added !

Comment: Yes i'm using Authorization: token TOKENVALUE

Comment: postman image broken, please share here

Comment: Broken ? You can't open it ?

Comment: @KévinBuzit Are you sure that MyToken is the right token ?

Comment: 100% sure about that, controlled it with Breakpoints

Comment: I have the same issue. If there's any other option than restarting the server which I cannot control, please share.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem in my implementation. I've explored various solutions, but none of them have been effective so far. Eventually, I discovered that Postman handles HTTP redirection automatically. However, when using RestSharp for implementation, the headers we initially set are not included in the redirected request.

Here is the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947731/8403632

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of auth you're using,  but I use a firebase token generated at runtime,  and this is the only thing I could get to work for me.

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + _fireBaseService.AuthToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem in my implementation. I've explored various solutions, but none of them have been effective so far. Eventually, I discovered that Postman handles HTTP redirection automatically. However, when using RestSharp for implementation, the headers we initially set are not included in the redirected request.

To verify, disable the "Automatically follow redirects" setting in Postman. After turning off this setting, if the issue still persists in Postman, it indicates that the problem lies in the extraction process.

[image]

So I added a check that resends the API request of receiving a 401 with the below code.

```
... rest of your code

RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

int numericStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
if (numericStatusCode == 401)
{
       var redirectedClient = new RestClient(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
       var newResponse = redirectedClient.Execute(request);
       Console.WriteLine(newResponse.ResponseStatus);
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
var url = $"{_apiCredentials.DataServer}/test/data/contracts/";

var options = new RestClientOptions(url)
{
       MaxTimeout = -1,
       Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(
                accessToken.Token, // Update the token
                "Bearer")
};

var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Get);

RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

int numericStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
if (numericStatusCode == 401)
{
      var redirectedClient = new 
      RestClient(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
      var newResponse = redirectedClient.Execute(request);
      Console.WriteLine(newResponse.ResponseStatus);
}
```